# how to send datatype as a parameter

Tags: c#, winforms

i work on a winform project and i want to know how can i send data type to a function and verify if a variable type inside this function is the same type that i sent to the function

i use this way but i got an error

```
public bool check_with_MESSAGE(ref dynamic TX, Type TP, string MESSAGE)
    {
        if (TX is TP)
        {
            ERROR = new support_forms.ERROR_MESSAGE_FRM(MESSAGE);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This sounds very much like a XY problem. Could you please tell us why you even use dynamic to begin with?

Comment: I need this function to verify the type of some variables that i will send to it, that's why i use dyncamic cause i don't know the exact type of the variable that i want to send to the function and im so sorry about my level in English

Comment: You still might not need `dynamic`.  Wouldn't `object` be enough?  Also, since you aren't assigning anything to TX (as in, no calls to `TX = ...`, you don't need the `ref` keyword either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class SomeClass
{
    public bool check_with_MESSAGE(ref dynamic TX, Type TP, string MESSAGE)
    {
        if (TX.GetType() == TP)
        {
            //Whatever this is...
            //ERROR = new support_forms.ERROR_MESSAGE_FRM(MESSAGE);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    // Proof
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var someClass = new SomeClass();

        dynamic instance = "This is a string";

        var isString = someClass.check_with_MESSAGE(ref instance, typeof(string), "Some message");

        var isInt = someClass.check_with_MESSAGE(ref instance, typeof(int), "Some message");

        Console.WriteLine($"instance is string: {isString}, instance is int: {isInt}");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: didn;t work bro, i need to send type to the function and it verify the TX if his type is the same datatype that i sent to the function

Comment: I agree - this answer should be correct for checking if the Type of TX equals TP.  Is it possible you really want to check if TX _inherits_ or _implements_ TP?